# java: ldap NamingException

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I try to use LDAP authentication.

```
public boolean login(String username, String password){
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person")).and(new EqualsFilter("uid", username));
    return ldapTemplate.authenticate(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, filter.toString(), password);
}
```

Because I used ActiveDirectory server, I have this exception:

> javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-03100754, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0]; remaning name = '/'

In my opinion, this exception showed, because I use `DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH`.

How I can to fix this problem?

Comment: I trying to use ldapTemplate.authenticate(ctxt.getNameInNamespace(), filter.toString(), password); and other variations, but my problem not solved...

Comment: There is no `uid`in active directory bu only `sAMAccountName`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The actual error you have is the following:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_DS_MISSING_SUPREF
//
// MessageText:
//
//  No superior reference has been configured for the 
//  directory service. The directory service is therefore 
//  unable to issue referrals to objects outside this forest.
//
#define ERROR_DS_MISSING_SUPREF          8406L
```

This can be found by converting the error code you have (**000020D6**) into decimal and checking in winerror.h.

In my opinion you need to supply a base DN for the search you are performing. The one you have supplied (supposedly by default, when not specified) is **/**, which is not a valid DN. If you domain name is *domain.example.com*, a valid base DN will be *DC=domain,DC=example,DC=com*.

Comment: Thanks a lot every body.